# Cant access WP-Admin due to port change

Tags: php, wordpress

I was trying to use one worpdress plugin and in the process changed the port in the plugins admin screen
 Now the problem is i can t log in access my WP-Admin as it is point to the changed port 443
How can i revert it to use the default port again. I am not that strong in Linux and using Cpanel to do my file management..

Error
     04 Not Found
The server can not find the requested page:

www.xxxxx.com/wp-admin/ (port 443)

Answer (score 1):

**First Way**

1. login to your ftp/cpanel filemanager and search for wp-config.php file
2. then open it and u will see a line like
   `define( 'force_SSL', true );
3. change the "true" to become "false" and save it.
4. the login to yr website backend again.
5. If here u r able to login already, mean its good! go to plugin page and disable it.
6. However, if still not accessible for you. You may need to look into .htacess file. Try rename the .htaccess to .htaccess.bak

**second way** is manually disable the plugin using Cpanel - > phpmyadmdmin

please read: http://perishablepress.com/quickly-disable-or-enable-all-wordpress-plugins-via-the-database/

**(Update)**

add these to wp-config.php

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://www.sample.com/wordpress');
define('WP_HOME', 'http://www.sample.com/wordpress');
```

see if it help?

Comment: My wp-config file  does not contain such a the line define( 'force_SSL', true );

Comment: try add 1 : define( 'force_SSL', false);

Comment: Tried that as well still not working. I know you know better than i do in this as I am relatively new to Wordpress but i think the issue here is the port. I had set the port to 443 before exiting the admin panel and then could not access it after. So if i could find a way to make the wp-admin URL use the default port i think it would be fine.I jsut dont know where to change or set that